# Is there a way for an app to know when others start?

Tags: android

I realize that you can receive intents from other apps, and that you can start other apps from your app. But is there a way to, from an app, detect when another app has started? Or even to detect when any of your apps have started?

Comment: When onCreate is called. Though I know that is likely not possible as you cannot access another app' activity life cycle. But I wanted to know if there's a way to perhaps to detect currently running apps to be able to tell when an app is started or some other way.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182046/how-can-one-detect-an-android-application-launching. However, this question hints at a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched