# Is there a listener that is triggered on return to the Application?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to trigger an action such as showing a popUp on the Home activity of my application when the application is launched or if it was running in the back ground and was brought to front again.

My problem is that there is no onResume() or onRestart() for the Application class, and at the home activity's side there no way of telling if the previous activity was not coming from the my application or not to decide on showing the popup or not.

is there a listener that can be trigged on return to the application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually put it in the `onCreate()` method, and do a test for what **`intent`** it has been passed. That way you can distinguish when it's been called from another of your activities.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to read the task stack, or determine if the user came from the home screen, see: [Android - detecting application launch from home or history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447912/android-detecting-application-launch-from-home-or-history)

Comment: hi and thanks for the quick response, the onCreate() method is only called once for the application instance, if the applicaiton is running is the background and was brought to front again onCreate will not be invoked again so that's no good for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for everyone, but why not create a base class for the activities in your project? Then you would have access to `onResume()` and `onRestart()`.

If you are extending other SDK Activities (`ListActivity`, etc), you could create base flavors of those classes and move the code called in `onResume()` and `onRestart()` to a utility class so that the same logic can be called from any "base" Activity.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but this is not my problem i already have those implemented in my Activity, however the problem is that i would like to be notified when the Applicaiton is launched or relaunched to perform specific action, this doesn't apply to the onResume() and onRestart() methods of the activity class which are called when ever an activity (not application) is invoked :)