# FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY not set in Nexus 10 (Android 4.4.2)

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a main activity A which will call another activity B whose oncreate() is mentioned below. When I press home button while in activity B and press recent apps, the flag  FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY is never set. I'm using a samsung nexus 10 (Android 4.4.2).

```
 protected void onStart() {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0)
  {
       //Call Main Activity.
  }
  else
  {
       //Continue creating this activity
  }
 }
```

When I placed the if block in onCreate() it would never get called when I open my app from recent apps.

**EDIT 1**:
Let me explain what I wanted to do. Whenever the user makes the application to go to the background (locking the screen, pressing home button etc), I want to call a particular activity (for authentication) when the app comes to the foreground.

Comment: You seem to be implying that it is set on other devices/versions.  Can you specifically confirm that is the case?  Can you try on an emulator with a similar Android version?

Answer (score 8):

I think you are confused. If your main activity starts ActivityB, then `ActivityB.onCreate()` will be called and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` will not be set. Now, with ActivityB in the foreground, you press the HOME button. This task is pushed to the background. Later the user opens the list of recent tasks and selects your application. The task (with ActivityB on top) is simply brought to the foreground. ActivityB **is not recreated**, therefore `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` will still not be set. ActivityB.onCreate()` **is not called again**.

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` is only set if Android creates a new instance of your activity when the user selects the app from the list of recent tasks. In most cases, this will be when the user starts your application again (from the beginning) after all your activities have finished.

Comment: Is there any other way by which I could identify whether an app is brought to foreground from recent tasks?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? What are you trying to do? Explain that because there may be an easier way to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: In general, `onPause()` will be called when your activity is being covered by another activity (including lock screen). `onResume()` will be called when your activity is brought to the foreground again. However, `onResume()` is also called when your activity is started for the first time, after `onCreate(), onStart()` are called. So you probably want to set a flag in `onCreate()` and then clear the flag in `onResume()`. Only if the flag is clear upon entry to `onResume()` would you need to show the authentication activity.