# Android: Detect App Launch

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am developing a lock application as an academic project. I need to detect the launch of an app so that i can launch my lockscreen on top of it and restrict opening the app till the user put correct pin. I have read a few posts and this one has a few answers that look promising.

[Android, Detect when other apps are launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

Is this the right way to do it? Or is there a better way around? I have also heard about the `Application` class. But don't know how to implement it.

EDIT: My app supports API16 to API22.

Comment: if you read some of the comments mentioned it is not working after jellybean

Comment: and also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447912/android-detecting-application-launch-from-home-or-history