# How to detect resume state of application instead of activity?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have two situations

1. A main activity from which I start another activities and return back to the main activity from this activity.
2. My whole application is in the background and I'm returning to the main     activity.

How could I identify these two situations separately? I think  `onRestart` and `onResume` methods can't help me because both these methods will be called on both situation.

Comment: This link may be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447912/android-detecting-application-launch-from-home-or-history#14941514

Comment: create base activity and inherit from that on all activities, override onPause and onResume in baseActivity, in onPause run one handle with 1 second postDelay, if on resume called before running handler code, stop handler. in handle code change one boolean value that application goes to background. in onResume or any where else check that

Answer (score 1):

To identify the two situation in your question, you can follow these steps:

1. In you main activity, use `startActivityForResult` to start other acitivities with requestCode >= 0
2. override `onActivityResult` method in main activity to handle the event when you return back from other activity.
3. call `setResult` in other activity before you want to return to the main acitivty.

your second situation would not trigger `onAcvitityResult` method.